# Angular6 Material table width error

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I generated new project, and added:

> ng add @angular/material

and

> ng generate @angular/material:material-table --name *data-liste*

The problem is the table not using all the available space see pictures:
Picture before added more columns

[image]

after adding columns

[image]

I haven't changed any css or html (besides pic2 changed html to allow more col.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use table css in css file

```
table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Read [**Document**](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview)

[**Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/angular/mooqolxdvjoe?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts)